# A/B Test with Rails resets data after version change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, ab-testing

I'm using split gem on Rails and my experiments keeps incrementing it's version, and after each increment all the data are lost. I don't know the pattern for it to change thus don't know how to prevent it. For example:

```
Experiment: landing v19 Goal:view-wheels
ALTERNATIVE NAME    PARTICIPANTS    NON-FINISHED    COMPLETED   CONVERSION RATE
A                       70               40            30          42.86%
B                       70               27            43          61.43% +43.33%
```

After some event that I don't know, the version will change to v20 and all data will be lost. I want to prevent it, I need to keep counting until I actively say to stop.

My redis configuration:

On redis.rb:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password, :username => uri.user)
```

On split.rb:

```
require "split/dashboard"
include Split::Helper
Split.redis = REDIS

Split.configure do |config|
  config.experiments = {
      "landing" => {
        :alternatives => ["A", "B"],
        :resettable => false,
        :goals => ["opt-in", "view-wheels"]
      }
    }
  config.db_failover = true # handle redis errors gracefully
  config.db_failover_on_db_error = proc{|error| Rails.logger.error(error.message) }
end
```